# I keep getting an "Unsupported Media Type" error using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey

So I am having trouble with REST (which I am a beginner at). I would like to PUT a multipart form to a certain URL. I had accomplished this with Jersey from an example I found on the web, unfortunately in my project I am supposed to use the spring framework web client. Below is my working Jersey Code.

```
// setup properties
String publishUrl = "http://localhost:8080/url/to/rest/api";
File schemaFile = new File("myfile.xml");
String catalogName = "myFileName";

FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(schemaFile);
String jndiName = "myJNDI";
boolean overwrite = true;
boolean enableXmla = true;

//set up multi part form. 
FormDataMultiPart part = new FormDataMultiPart()
        .field("uploadAnalysis", inputStream, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
        .field("catalogName", catalogName, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
        .field("Datasource", jndiName, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
        .field("overwrite", overwrite ? "true" : "false", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
        .field("xmlaEnabledFlag", enableXmla ? "true" : "false", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
        .field("parameters", "Datasource=" + jndiName, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

// If the import service needs the file name do the following.
part.getField("uploadAnalysis").setContentDisposition(FormDataContentDisposition.name("uploadAnalysis").fileName(schemaFile.getName()).build());

//set up client and create web resource
Client client = Client.create();
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("Admin", "password"));

WebResource resource = client.resource(publishUrl);
ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE).put(ClientResponse.class, part);

System.out.println(response.getStatus());
```

This works fine. So now I have tried to transcribe this over to work with the spring web client. The following is my current code

```
//setup properties
String publishUrl = "http://localhost:8080/url/to/rest/api";
File schemaFile = new File("myFile.xml");
String catalogName = "myFileName";
String jndiName = "myJNDI";
boolean overwrite = true;
boolean enableXmla = true;

//setup form
MultiValueMap<String, Object> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
form.add("uploadAnalysis", new FileSystemResource(schemaFile));
form.add("catalogName", catalogName);
form.add("Datasource", jndiName);
form.add("overwrite", overwrite ? "true" : "false");
form.add("xmlaEnabledFlag", enableXmla ? "true" : "false");
form.add("parameters", "Datasource=" + jndiName);

//Set up credentials
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("Admin", "password"));

//set up http client
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();

//create client request factory using httpcient
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory fact = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpclient);

//create rest template
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate(fact);

//create http headers
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

//use put method. 
rt.put(publishUrl, headers, form);
```

This code does not work, I always get the following error:

```
 WARN  26-04 14:57:11,988 - PUT request for "http://localhost:8080/url/to/rest/api" resulted in 415 (Unsupported Media Type); invoking error handler
```

I am a bit confused by this because in Jersey I set the MediaType to "MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE" and in Spring I set it to "MULTIPART_FORM_DATA" so I am not sure why this would give me a unsupported media type. Any ideas would be helpful.

**Edit**

So I changed my code to not use the .put() method as I was using it wrong, the changes look like this.

```
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(form, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = rt.exchange(publishUrl, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);
```

However, after making these changes I am getting a no response error

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost:8080/url/to/rest/api":localhost:8080 failed to respond; nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8080 failed to respond
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:543)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:489)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:431)
```

The odd thing is the that the **file is uploaded to the server**, however I dont get any response from the server. Is there some type of header I have to set to get a response or something? When using Jersey I would get a response every time, so I am wondering if there was something pre-configured in jersey that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `RestTemplate#put(...)` incorrectly. The 3rd argument is meant to be a `Map` of URI variables. Instead use one of the [`RestTemplate#exchange(..)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange%28java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.http.HttpMethod,%20org.springframework.http.HttpEntity,%20org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference,%20java.util.Map%29) methods where you can pass an `HttpEntity` with the appropriate headers.

Comment: I changed this put method to 
  `HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(form, headers);
  
  ResponseEntity<String> response = rt.exchange(publishUrl, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);` but am now getting a message saying that localhost:8080 failed to respond..

Comment: @decal That would seem to indicate your server is down.

Comment: well its definitely not, this is why I am a bit confused, Jersey uploads the file just fine.

Comment: @decal Are you saying you get a network exception? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://localhost:8080/url/to/rest/api":localhost:8080 failed to respond; nested exception is org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8080 failed to respond
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:543)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:489)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:431)`

Comment: @decal Yeah, seems like a network error. (Put your stack traces and other code in edits to your question, they're easier to read.) Try pinging your server.